# PDAL: Argument references invalid/unused stage: 'filters.voxelgrid'

Tags: error, lidar, mac, point-cloud, pdal

I am running into an error when running [`pdal translate`](https://www.pdal.io/apps/translate.html) on Mac OS High Sierra:

```
PDAL: Argument references invalid/unused stage: 'filters.voxelgrid'.
```

This is the command I am using based on a [PDAL tutorial on thinning point cloud data](https://www.pdal.io/tutorial/dart-throwing.html):

```
$ pdal translate -i /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54.laz -o /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54-thinned.laz --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_x=4.5 --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_y=4.5 --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_z=4.5
```

Essentially, this command thins the point cloud data with a voxel grid algorithm.

I see that the `filters.voxelgrid` driver is enabled when I call `pdal --drivers`. I'm using `pdal 1.6.0` which was installed using `brew install pdal`. I am also running `pcl 1.8.1_2`, which was installed by default during the brew install of pdal.

What might be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdal translate` requires the filter type `voxelgrid`.

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
$ pdal translate -i /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54.laz -o /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54-thinned.laz voxelgrid --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_x=4.5 --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_y=4.5 --filters.voxelgrid.leaf_z=4.5
```

Same command with each parameter separated for legibility:

```
$ pdal translate \
-i /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54.laz \
-o /Users/aaron/temp/1958-09-54-thinned.laz \
voxelgrid \
--filters.voxelgrid.leaf_x=4.5 \
--filters.voxelgrid.leaf_y=4.5 \
--filters.voxelgrid.leaf_z=4.5
```